# Using Rlike in Hive to find Regex patterns

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to filter a column to check for words like head, att, space etc and I am using the following query

```
select * from tablename where (column_name like '%head%' or column_name like '%att%' or column_name like '%space%')
```

But the problem with the query is, it filters out even words like headgear, attitude, spaceship. I want to filter only rows that have particular word like head, att, space. I tried putting a space to each word,

```
select * from tablename where (column_name like '%head %' or column_name like '%att %' or column_name like '%space %')
```

But this doesn't filter the word, if head is present towards the end of the sentence.

Just figured out that we can use something like `rlike` in Hive to solve this issue. But I tried doing it without much success.

Can anybody help me in using `rlike` to filter only rows that contain only words like head, att, space.

Thanks

Adding update..

Suppose the input is as follow

```
Tom's head
my head is big
I am having headache
att is bad
attitude is bad
bad is att
There is more space
spaceship
space is looking cool
```

The output should be,

```
Tom's head
my head is big
att is bad
bad is att
There is more space
space is looking cool
```

The following rows should be removed because I am only interested on words like head, att and space, whenever it occurs in the sentence. I am not interested in filtering headache, attitude and spaceship.

```
I am having headache
attitude is bad
spaceship
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`RLIKE` uses the common regular expressions syntax that we have in majority of the programming languages.

`^head$` denotes that the column should start (start in denoted by `^`) and end (end is denoted by `$`)with `head`.

For example, if you want to filter words that start with `h` and ends with `d`, you can do something like this: `^h.*d$`. The solution to your question above is this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE
(
  column_name RLIKE '^head$' OR
  column_name RLIKE '^att$' OR
  column_name RLIKE '^space$'
);
```

Ref: [Relational Operators](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-RelationalOperators)

Comment: Kiran Thanks for you reply. Head could even be inside the column, instead of starting with head. like Tom's head. Does this one work for that as well ?

Comment: No, it doesn't work for that. I'll get back to you with the updated statement. Can you add all the testcases in your question so that I can test my statement and give you the correct answer.

Comment: kiran Just did that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

word boundary will work for this scenario, it captures the string at the start, middle and at the end.

```
with aa as
(select 'Toms head' as col1
union all
select 'head as in headache' as col1
union all
select 'headache as in head' as col1
union all
select 'my head is big' as col1
union all
select 'I am having headache' as col1
union all
select 'att is bad' as col1
union all
select 'attitude is bad' as col1
union all
select 'bad is att' as col1
union all
select 'There is more space' as col1
union all
select 'spaceship' as col1
union all
select 'space is looking cool' as col1)
select col1 from aa
where regexp(col1,'\\bhead\\b|\\batt\\b|\\bspace\\b')
```